# undefined index product in prestashop 1.6.1.4

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I get these errors with undefined index product from my prestashop 1.6 and i don't know how to fix this errors. 
Some help needed here.

I'm new with this! Good day to all.

Here are the error log lines:

> [02-Nov-2017 10:22:33 Europe/Bucharest] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
>   product in
>   /home/zuzavetr/public_html/modules/labhoverflipimg/labhoverflipimg.php
>   on line 40
>
> [02-Nov-2017 10:22:33 Europe/Bucharest] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
>   product in
>   /home/zuzavetr/public_html/modules/labhoverflipimg/labhoverflipimg.php
>   on line 60

My PHP file labhoverflipimg.php:

```
    <?php
    class labhoverflipimg extends Module {
        public function __construct() {
            $this->name         = 'labhoverflipimg';
            $this->tab          = 'front_office_features';
            $this->version      = '1.1';
            $this->author       = 'labersthemes';
            $this->displayName  = $this->l('Hover flip img');
            $this->description  = $this->l('Hover flip img');
            parent :: __construct();
        }

        public function install() {
           // Install SQL
            include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/install.php');
            foreach ($sql as $s)
                if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($s))
                    return false;
            return parent :: install()
                && $this->registerHook('rotatorImg')
                && $this->registerHook('header')
                ;
        }

        public function uninstall(){
            include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/uninstall_sql.php');
            foreach ($sql as $s)
                if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($s))
                    return false;
            return parent::uninstall();
        }

        public function psversion() {
            $version=_PS_VERSION_;
            $exp=$explode=explode(".",$version);
            return $exp[1];
        }

        public function hookRotatorImg($params) {
                $idproduct = $params['product']['id_product'];
                $id_shop = (int)Context::getContext()->shop->id;
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'image` img'; 
                $sql .= ' LEFT JOIN `'. _DB_PREFIX_ . 'image_shop` imgs';
                $sql .= ' ON img.id_image = imgs.id_image';
                $sql .= ' where imgs.`id_shop` ='.$id_shop ;
                $sql .= ' AND img.`id_product` ='.$idproduct ;
                $sql .= ' AND imgs.`rotator` =1' ;
                //echo $sql;
                $imageNew = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
                if(!$imageNew) {
                      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'image` img'; 
                      $sql .= ' where img.`rotator` =1';
                      $sql .= ' AND img.`id_product` ='.$idproduct ;
                      $imageNew = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
                }

                $this->smarty->assign(
                    array('rotator_img'=>$imageNew,
                    'idproduct'=>$idproduct,
                    'product'=>$params['product'],
                    ));

            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'labhoverflipimg.tpl');
        }    

        public function hookdisplayHeader($params)
        {
            $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/labhoverflipimg.css', 'all');
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: No one is gonna go entire all the file's code. Mention, separately, the related lines (939, 951). BTW, it seems that the error is in the file "labproductcategory.php" while your code is of another file.

Comment: Please edit the question with the `labproductcategory` file.

Comment: Sorry, i was mistake. i have edited my question with the corect error file